# Conterexample of corollary of Komlós theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I read an article, and they use a certain theorem, called Komlós theorem, which says:

> ***Theorem 1*** (Komlós theorem)
>
> Let $(E,\mathcal {A}, \mu ) $ be a finite measure space and  $ (f_n)_{n\geq 1} \subset \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1$ is a sequence  with : $$\sup_n \int_{E}{|f_n| d\mu} < \infty .$$
> Then there exist $ h _{\infty} \in  \mathcal {L}_{\mathbb {R}}^1 $ and a sub-sequence $ (g_k)_k $ of $(f_n)_n $  such that for every sub-sequence $ (h_m)_m $ of $(g_k)_k$ : $$ \frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}{h_j}\to   h _{\infty} \text{ a.s. }$$

The original Komlós theorem concerns $\mathcal{L}^1_\mathbb{R}$-bounded sequence of functions. The following theorem gives a similar result for nonnegative valued measurable functions.

> ***Theorem 2***
>
> Let $ (f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of nonnegative valued measurable functions.
>
> Then there exist a sub-sequence $ (g_k)_k $ of $(f_n)_n $ and a measurable function $h _{\infty}$ such that for every sub-sequence $ (h_m)_m $ of $(g_k)_k$ : $$ \frac{1}{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}{h_j}\to   h _{\infty} \text{ a.s. }$$

**My problem:**
I want a counterexample of a sequence of measurable functions such that the second theorem is not valid. An idea please